# "Your margins are pretty small..." errors when printing

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, microsoft-word-2013

On sending to print I receive the following message:

> Your margins are pretty small. Some of your content might be cut off
>   when you print. Do you still want to print?

- I don't know why it appears.
- There's no wrong setting for the printer itself.
- If I ignore the popup - the printed paper comes out fine and clear.

Is there a way to cancel the pop-up of this particular message?

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-word/how-to-get-rid-of-the-your-margins-are-pretty/71d27fd0-fcca-4dfa-8702-2284f74080cc

Comment: @CaldeiraG Why not make an answer?

Comment: Have you check if your chosen paper size is too small? The problem might also be because your printer does not allow full-width prints. Most printers do not.

Comment: It's a A4 paper.
Maybe I'm being a dummy and possibly overlooked something.

Comment: As mentioned, this is a printer setting.  

1) Either it's the paper size, maybe the printer is set up for a smaller paper size than you have told Word.
2) Or the Printer margins are incorrect - Look at the setup in the printer.

Answer (score 0):

From a [Microsoft MVP](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-word/how-to-get-rid-of-the-your-margins-are-pretty/71d27fd0-fcca-4dfa-8702-2284f74080cc):

> The unprintable area respected by Word is specified by the printer driver, not by Word itself. Word gets the information from the printer driver, so unless you can redefine the unprintable area in the printer Property settings, there may be no way around this message.

So, in order for the warning to disappear you will need to print with atleast the minimum margins specified from your printer (will depend of your printer but some sources defines as 0.17 inches as the "default" minimum).

You can always ignore the popup since it's only a warning.

Comment: I am aware that Word relies on the printer settings.
Yet, the settings are set as 0cm and are perfect when looking at what comes out.
Unfortunately - ignoring the popup (i.e. clicking 'ignore' for every page printed) increases the workload for my colleagues.

Comment: @WhisperGnome try to look at your printer settings for [Edge to Edge printing](https://filestore.community.support.microsoft.com/api/images/50233945-a1d9-4ac1-aec6-d1d52aea19e9?upload=true). On an alternative measure just convert the documents to PDF and print it like that.

Comment: That's the thing - even when printing to PDF or OneNote, I keep getting the margin messages.